# Drupal - linking Taxonomies together with views in a sequence

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have something in Drupal (v6) that i'm trying to nail, but having a little difficulty. I am laying out a list of products which have the following taxonomy vocabularies attached to them:

- Manufacturer
- Product Type
- Use

When entering a product, which uses a custom content type, the admin can select one or more terms from each of these vocabs.

I then need to lay the front-end out using Views as follows:

1. List of Manufacturers displayed to the user - user clicks one
2. List of Product Types displayed to the user that have a product contained within that matches the chosen Manufacturer - user clicks one
3. List of Uses displayed to the user that have a product contained within that matches the chosen Manufacturer and Product Type - user clicks one to view full node details

The tricky bit is making the link between each of these vocabs using Views. The taxonomy vocabs have no hierarchy defined within them, I just need to be able to display them to the user in the order above. I can't change to using a nested hierarchy in just one vocabulary as the 3 seperate vocabs are used elsewhere on the site for other purposes and need to stay as they are.

Is it possible to create what i'm after with Views? Any tips on how best to rig it together?

Answer (score 0):

Could use 3 views, with the 2nd and 3rd taking arguments.

So a url could look like:

/products/ - 1st view
/products/Ford - 2nd view, one argument
/products/Ford/Cars - 3rd view, two args

That said, for something like this I'd probably just write a custom module. How practical that is depends on how comfortable you are with Drupal and PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems easy enough when I see it written down, but I can't quite glue it together. Do you know of any examples online I could look at?

Comment: Not really. It's pretty basic views arguments stuff, so just look at docs like that.